# Kotlin with Spring - perform actions after response

Tags: spring, kotlin

I'm using Spring to answer a few http requests using Kotlin.
I wanna perform an action (specifically monitoring action) that has nothing to do with the response to the user, therefore I'd like to perform it after the response so there would be no penalty for the user.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried using [coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally do this by using some kind of queueing/messaging/action system that passes this work onto another thread.

In Spring, you could start a service that performs these actions for you. This service can then leverage [coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html) to do the actual work in a background thread.

Alternatively/additionally, if your actions take up a long time, you could use a [message queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) system to handle these actions. There are various message queue projects, like RabbitMQ, that allow you to create messages on one machine, and let them be handled on 1 or more other machines. That way, your front-end server can leave some of the hard work to other servers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! the action should not take more than a few milliseconds but it still time I don't wanna add to the route if not necessary, I can use RabbitMQ but feels like a bit overkill for that. What did you mean my "queueing/messaging/action system"?

Comment: If you have lots of actions to trigger, if your actions can take long to process, or if you need to process them in sequence across various HTTP requests, you can create a queue system to handle them. With a message queue, your actions are described/wrapped into a "message" and then sent over to the queue for processing. RabbitMQ and Kafka are popular systems that provide this functionality.